# A question about tensor product and hom functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings with units, $M$ an $A$-module, $N$ a $B$-module, and $P$ an $A\text{-}B$-bimodule. I want to prove
$$\hom_A(M, \hom_B(P,N)) \cong \hom_B(M \otimes_A P,N).$$
I can give a map from RHS to LHS, but when I want to give a map from LHS to RHS, I can't make a map from $M \otimes_A P$ to $N$.
Please help me.

Comment: How are maps $M \otimes P \rightarrow N$ defined?

Comment: They are $B$-modules, so maps are $B$-module homomorphisms.

Comment: No, I meant: what is, by definition, a $M \otimes  P \rightarrow N$?

Comment: We need a bilinear map from $M \times P$ to $N$, but $N$ is not a $A$-module, so I don't know how to do.

Comment: The property on the corresponding maps $M \times P \rightarrow N$ is actually *quasi*-bilinearity, ie $f(a \cdot m,p)=f(m,a \cdot p)$ (and $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear). Since the tensor version of $f$ has to be $B$-linear, this means $f(m,b \cdot p)=b \cdot f(m,p)$. Given an $A$-map $M \rightarrow Hom(P,N)$, (ie $g(a \cdot m)=g(m) \circ (a \cdot id_P)$), how would you construct $f$ naturally?

Comment: I can construct $f(m,p)=g_m(p)$. Actually I don't know why the quasi-bilinearity can make sure that the map from $M \otimes P$ to $N$ well defined.

Comment: $f(am,p)=g_{am}(p)=g_m \circ (a ~ \mathrm{id}_P)(p)=g_m(ap)=f(m,ap)$.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify this question. The tensor product I learned is that $(M \otimes P, \otimes)$ is a module and a bilinear map such that for any module $N$ and any bilinear map $M \times P \to N$, there exists a unique module homomprphism $M \otimes P \to N$ such that they are commutative. I can verify the quasi-bilinearity, but I don't know why this condition can make the map $M \otimes P \to N$ well defined.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what your issue is. But perhaps you can check that it works by coming back to a construction of the tensor product?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to do. Let $F$ be the free module generated by the elements $M \times P$, and $T$ the submodule generated by $$\begin{gather}(m_1+m_2,p)-(m_1,p)-(m_2,p),(m,p_1+p_2)-(m,p_1)-(m,p_2), \\ (am,p)-a(m,p),(m,ap)-a(m,p), \end{gather}$$ then $F/T$ is the tensor product I learned. Then how do we make the map according to a quasi-bilinear map? I really think this is not trivial, or this formula is wrong in this case.

Comment: Assume $f: M \times P \rightarrow N$ is quasi-bilinear. You have a natural additive map $\hat{f}: F \rightarrow T$ given, eg, by $\hat{f}(a \cdot (m,p))=f(am,p)$. Now you just need to check $\hat{f}(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your patient explanation.